# Is there any way to print the powerbi-embedded report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Embeddded the report using powerbi-client-angular-wrapper demo code. Is there any option to view the report in fullscreen and print the embedded report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using powerbi-client-angular wrapper demo code, Use Apis to view the report in fullscreen and print the report.

```
this.reportObj.getReport().fullscreen(); // View the report in fullscreen
this.reportObj.getReport().print(); // Print the report
```

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embedding-basic-interactions